# Box collider inside Box collider affects game performance?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm planning to create empty Gameobject and attach a box collider in it for my touch sensor then inside of it is another empty Gameobject with a box collider for detection of collision. Does this affect game performance cause every update   it detects a collision? Please don't say that just remove the inside gameobject then attach the collision to the outer gameobject.

[image]

Comment: it should not matter much. when in doubt - benchmark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While **it does** trigger `OnCollisionStay` every frame by default, you can use the **Layer Collision Matrix** to disable this behaviour for the selected Layers.

Even if you don't, the performance difference will be *neglectable*, unless we're talking about thousands of objects, and a really unoptimized `OnCollisionStay` function.

You can find the Layer Collision Mask settings under the Physics settings.
(Link: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicsManager.html)

---

The other approach would be to just disable collision for the two colliders, like this:

```cs
void Awake() {
    Collider col = GetComponent<Collider>();
    Collider parentCol = transform.parent.GetComponent<Collider>();
    Physics.IgnoreCollision(col, parentCol, true);
}
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.IgnoreCollision.html

---

I usually don't even bother using any of the methods above to disable collision for objects that are not massly produced, and instead use this kind of logic:

```cs
void OnCollisionStay(Collision col) {
    // Skip if it's the object we don't care about
    if (col.gameObject == transform.parent.gameObject) { return; }

    // Could also check by layer
    if (col.gameObject.layer == 8) { return; }

    // Rest of the OnCollisionStay function
}
```

Comment: This works. For additional info I'm using 2D so I use Physics2D.IgnoreCollision then   change Collider  to Collider2D.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned that the two colliders will collide with each other every frame, you don't have to worry. You can put their objects on two  different layers and configure it in such a way that they don't collide with each other. You will need to do that anyway cause otherwise your touch sensor collider will interact with the game world. 
You can learn more here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html